# How to limit database insert action based on value in other table

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 SQL tables:

- Employee
- Technician
- Manager

Technican and Manager each extend Employee. Employee has a field `employeeType` which can be equal to `Manager`, `Technician` or `Technician/Manager`.

Is there any way to check inside the Technician table to make sure that only employees with an employee type of `Technician/Manager` or `Technician` can be insert?

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: I have done my best to edit your question's formatting, but I think you still need to provide some details. Are you looking to do this via application logic or some kind of db constraint?

Comment: Thanks for editing the format. Will look into that before asking more questions. I am only using PhpMyAdmin so a db constraint would probably be best

Comment: Have you tried using `triggers` ?

Comment: I think before insert trigger will work for you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL?  Or another DB engine e.g. sql-server, oracle, etc you should tag the one you are using.  for sql-server a check constraint that refrences a scalar function should get you what you want, but for mysql you probably have to go the trigger route